# Problem with Piecewise constraint in Gurobi

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, python, gurobi

I am facing a problem in my model with piecewise constraints that is making my one of the decision variables equal to zero for every value.

My objective function is:

\begin{equation}
    \min \sum_{t=1}^T p_{t} \cdot (1+r) \cdot y_{t}    
\end{equation}
where $p$ is the price, $y$ is the quantity (decision variable) and $r$ is the price surcharge. $t$ is the index for time periods.

and my constraints are:

\begin{equation}
    M q_t > \sum_{i=0}^N \beta_{i} X_{it} - p_t (1+r) \quad \forall t=1,\dotsc,T
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    -M (1-q_t) \leq \sum_{i=0}^N \beta_{i} X_{it} - p_t (1+r)\quad  \forall t=1,\dotsc,T
\end{equation}

The problem is that the value of $r$ depends on which interval the value of $y$ (decision variable) lies as shown by the following piecewise function:

\begin{equation}
    r_t (Y_t) = 
    \begin{cases}
        % s_0
        0 & \mathrm{if }\; Y_t \leq b_0 \\
        % s_1
        0.05 & \mathrm{if }\; b_0 < Y_t \leq b_1 \\
        % s_2
        0.1 & \mathrm{if }\; b_1 < Y_t \leq b_2\\[6pt]
        ... & \mathrm{if }\; ...
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $b_0$, $b_1$ etc. are set of quantity intervals = [0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]

I have written piecewise constraints in Gurobi (Python) as:

```
for t in range(1, T + 1):
    m.addGenConstrPWL(quantity[t], r,
        [0, 50, 50, 100, 100, 150, 150, 200, 200, 250], 
        [0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2]
    )
    m.addConstr(-M * (1 - q[t]) <= gp.quicksum(beta[i] * X[i, t]
        for i in range(N + 1)) - p[t] * (1+r),
        name = "price threshold 1"
    )


for t in range(1, T + 1):
    m.addGenConstrPWL(quantity[t], r,
        [0, 50, 50, 100, 100, 150, 150, 200, 200, 250],
        [0, 0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2]
    )
    m.addConstr(M * q[t]) >= gp.quicksum(beta[i] * X[i, t]
        for i in range(N + 1)) - p[t] * (1+r),
        name = "price threshold 2"
    )
```

where $M$ is big M, $q[t]$ is binary variable, $X[i,t]$ is a given/known value, $\beta$ is a binary variable and $r$ also a binary variable.
There are also some other constraints but the problem is with these constraints.
Although the model optimizes the program it makes all the values of $\beta$ variable equal to zero which shouldn't be the case.

Could anyone please guide me where I am making mistake, whether in writing piecewise constraint or some other thing?

Comment: Please note that you cannot have strict inequalities (< or >) in math programming. To enforce a strict inequality, you would need to add a small constant term to either side of the inequality. Ignoring this might break your model's logic.